# JavaScript operator precedence (associativity)

Tags: javascript, operators, operator-precedence, associativity

I'm looking at the [JavaScript operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). What does n/a in associativity mean? For example, `new` has associativity of n/a, but I'm confused on why it's not left-to-right.

Comment: `new` is a keyword that initiates a procedure. Assigning something to the result of that procedure would be an LTR operation, but not the `new` call itself.

Comment: I think documentation is not correct there, the operators in the same precedence should have the same associativity.

Comment: That is a good question. Did you find an answer? "not available"? "[nonassociative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonassociative#Adjective)" (though it does not seem to apply here)? *"[not applicable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/n/a#Adjective)"*? [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N/A).